# interdependency of data between two methods called inside single method which is marked as @Transactional and both methods use different db connection

Tags: java, spring

In java, if I am keeping method as @transactional and inside that method calling another method of another jar which uses another db connection and dependent on data which will be received before calling it..issue is as both methods use different db connection..when second method tries to use data returned from first one find it "data not found" as the first method inside that whole method will be commited at the end because of @transactional status. what is the solution for this?

Comment: do you have any code with error?

Comment: No..currently I dont have code with error

Comment: Why are they even using different connections? If they share the same tx they should also use the same connection (assuming it is the same db).

Comment: Db is same..but what if I need to use the method of another jar which is using another connection..nd I cant make changes in that jar for passing connection to it

Comment: Then you have to change your design. You can't have a transactional method that calls both the data inserting method and the data using method. You'll have to make sure the data inserting method finishes its transaction before the other method is called.

Comment: is there any way to read uncommited data of first method by another method

Comment: Only if your database and driver supports the "read uncommitted" isolation level, which many don't. It would also be a bad solution attempting to fix bad design. Don't keep the method calls in the same transaction, or modify the design so they're not using different connections.

Comment: I tried to use read uncommited but still not working..

Comment: Too bad for you. I said "only if your database and driver supports it". Not all do.

Comment: ok ..thanks..I will try to redesign the method

Comment: Excellent choice!